# Share buttons on mobile app

Tags: mobile, mobile-application, social-media, share

I have an app (iOS and Android) that lists discounts (for restaurants and food in general).

I would like to implement the share option for every discount, so the user can tell other people about it.

I have two options:

1. One general button that opens the share options of each platform.
2. *3 - 4* options (WhatsApp, FB, Twitter, Email) and a general button that opens the share options of each platform.

What I would like to get are the maximum number of interactions, indepentently of the option I choose.

In your experience, what tends to be the best option of the two for this?

Some examples below

For option #1, this is **Uber Eats**:

[image]

For option #2, this is **Burpple**:

[image]

And this is **My App**, this is the screen where I will add the button(s):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have some experience with this; what it's told me is that how you **label, size and position** of your share icon are vastly more important than which icon you use.

Many people don't really have that deep of an understanding of sharing icons, even those that you might have thought were standard. More so on Android where the platform "share" icon has pretty bad understanding vs iPhone but still. If you want people to share you should use a labeled button.

The position is also important for people to be able to find it quickly. Tucked away in the title bar may not be easy - it's best to test if people see it.

As for expanding multiple choices in your app, I've found that it's not very useful and it's more work than you want to maintain (logos change, popular apps change and aren't the same from country to country...). 99% of people will use only one app to share, and by the time they hit the share button they already know what it is that they want to hit next.

Finally all this is general advice but nothing beats experimentation for this kind of optimization.

Answer (score 2):

We've had very poor response to the multiple sharing links on desktop sites. Less than a quarter of one percent of visitors to the page clicked on any of the share links.

Our sites will probably switch to a single share icon in a few months. The rationale there is, if the response rate is that bad, let's minimize the screen real estate taken by share icons.

Mobile usage may be better. Do you have a way to do element-level tracking in your app?

Comment: Could you state which sites you're talking about (or at least what types of users they cater to) and your monthly visit rate?

Comment: Sure, I work on a set of sites for a global manufacturer. It's primarily a B2B model. Our users are mostly middle-aged electrical engineers -- I guess they don't have much interest in social media.